# Java parse JSON from URL NullPointerException

Tags: java, json, parsing, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to parse the JSON from the following API:
https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1

but when I'm trying to get the question value, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I use this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String question;
    String sURL = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1"; //just a string

    // Connect to the URL using java's native library
    URL url = new URL(sURL);
    URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
    request.connect();

    // Convert to a JSON object to print data
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
    JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
    JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
    question = rootobj.get("question").getAsString(); //grab the question

}
```

Hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what line is the NullPointerException? did you try to debug the program?

Comment: IT is for line 10: 
    "question = rootobj.get("question").getAsString();"

Comment: so probably rootobj.get("question") is returning null, separate this line into 2 lines,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

question = rootobj.getAsJsonArray("results").get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("question").getAsString();

Answer (score 7):

When I look at the JSON you are trying to interpret, I get:

```
{
    "response_code": 0,
    "results":[
        {
            "category": "Entertainment: Board Games",
            "type": "multiple",
            "difficulty": "medium",
            "question": "Who is the main character in the VHS tape included in the board game Nightmare?",
            "correct_answer": "The Gatekeeper",
            "incorrect_answers":["The Kryptkeeper","The Monster","The Nightmare"]
        }
    ]
}
```

This JSON doesn't contain a root member `"question"`. This makes `rootobj.get("question")` return `null`, and therefore calling `getAsString` on it throws the `NullPointerException`.

So instead of `rootobj.get("question")`, you would have to walk through the hierarchy: `"results"` -> first array member -> `"question"`:

```
rootobj.getAsJsonArray("result").getAsJsonObject(0).get("question")
```

Answer (score 2):

The JSON has no direct "question" field.
call `question = rootobj.get("result").get(0).get("question").getAsString();` instead

Comment: Hmm just tryed your snippet but now is says "Cannot resolve method 'get(int)'"

Comment: That is right, your are using Gson parser and it has diffrent syntax.
Looks like @Daniel Przybylowski has the right syntax for you.